# page generator from template

Tags: php, sql, templates

I was wondering if there is a 'best' way to have a website with multiple pages with all pages having the same layout but with different content (like facebook, stackoverflow and many many other sites)?

The way I'm currently doing this is like this:

(the content in my case is a database tablename which is then queried into content through sql.)

template.php:

```
<?php 
function tplate($tablename){
echo "<html>content from $tablename</html>";
}
?>
```

subcat.php:

```
<?php
include 'template.php';
tplate('contenttable');
?>
```

This works in very simple cases but once I try to add more functionalities it gets really complicated and I spend a lot of time debugging.

Does anyone know how this is generally done/best handled?

Comment: you shoud take a look at template-systems like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) for example

Answer (score 1):

You'd typically use a templating engine (often in concert with a framework, like Laravel or Symfony). [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) is a popular one for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have been doing for a while http://controllingnetworks.tk/ the url is rewritten using a mod re-write, if i was to type the url in full it would be index.php?page=home instead of /home 
but all the pages have the same template with different content,
i have a few sites using databases to manage the content and a few that use php files to do this

Comment: if you want to know more about this and maybe one-to-one chat on skype, just pm me